# How can I get the value that is unique in a list?

Tags: python, list

If there's a list the elements of which are `[2,2,3,2,2]`. I want to find the element that is unique, which is `3` this time.

I think I could do this with `count()` method and a few loops, but I wonder if there are simpler and efficient ways to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> import collections
>>> l = [2,2,3,2,2]
>>> next(k for k, v in collections.Counter(l).items() if v == 1)
3
```

Comment: this will break if list doesn't have any unique element. e.g. l = [2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]

Comment: Add the default value as the 2nd argument for `next`, like `next(iter([]), 7)` -> `7`

Comment: Using the default argument of `next` would fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Without any modules, you can simply perform `xor` of all elements to get the unique item.

This outputs `0`, if there is no unique item as noted by @KeyurPotdar.

```
l = [2,2,3,2,2]

out = l[0]
for elem in l[1:]:
    out = out ^ elem

print(out)
# 3
```

Comment: This will give `0` as the output if no unique element is present. I think you should handle that case. For example, if `l = [0, 0, 0]`, output will be `0`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) and then [min](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min),

```
In [4]: from collections import Counter

In [5]: x = [2,2,3,2,2]

In [6]: c = Counter(x)

In [7]: min(c, key=c.get)
Out[7]: 3

In [8]:
```

Comment: He is asking if it is possible to get unique numbers only, set will return both 2 and 3

Comment: I see two problems here: 1) You're creating _two_ `Counter` objects instead of just one, which essentially doubles your execution time. 2) This will return the element with the least occurences, but it doesn't guarantee that that element occurs exactly once.